# Java Server - How to take input from InputStreamReader and convert to a String?

Tags: java, client, server, dataoutputstream, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to get a very simple `Client-Server` system to work, where the `Client` will send a String over to the `Server`, and the `server` will then store that String into a file.

***The client sends the string through:***

```
//Other Code

sockStrm = new DataOutputStream (clientSocket.getOutputStream ());

//Other code

sockStrm.writeChars (line);

//Other code
```

***And the Server receives the String with:***

```
//Other code 

strm = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (clientSocket.getInputStream ())); 

//Other code

stringLine = strm.readLine (); 

//Other code
```

When I send the string `STOP`, the length of the String is 4 on the client side, and on the server side the length of the String is 9 and displays as `STOP`

I've tried to substring the received String on the Server side, without luck.

***Any pointers on how to deal with this?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use symmetric methods:

```
DataOutputStream sockStrm =...
sockStrm.writeUTF(str);
```

and

```
DataInputStream sockStrm = ...
String str = sockStrm.readUTF();
```

writeChars writes individual characters as two byte values. Readers follow the encoding to reconstruct the string from a sequence of bytes, which will definitely not be according to high-byte-low-byte for each character code. Hence you get some mish-mash of zero bytes with the original low-byte values so you still have a glimpse of the original string value.
Using \x00 to denote a NULL byte:

```
S-T-O-P => on the line: \x00-S-\x00-T-\x00-O-\x00-P => prints as STOP
```

Use a loop over the characters of the incoming string and display their integer values (str.charAt(i)) to see the above for yourself.